# Hoverable tooltips with AJAX-pulled content on Prototype/Scriptaculous (to act like Twitter's)`

Tags: javascript, twitter, tooltip, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Twitter recently added hoverable multi-media "tooltips" -- when you hover over a username or avatar on your feed, it pops up (in-place) more details on the user (tweets sent/received, location, last tweet). It also includes a "Follow" button. There's a 'more-info' link which will load some more details on-demand.

I'd like to emulate how they're doing this-- which I think is a very elegant solution. There's a single empty/hidden div on the page, and on hover, that div is relocated to the appropriate place, display is set to "block" and populated with information (on-demand).

If I'm on the prototype/scriptaculous framework, is there a straightforward way of doing this same implementation? I don't have the ability to use other frameworks. Thank you in advance!

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Prototip](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/) - It offers an AJAX solution that does exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

[Opentip](http://www.opentip.org/) is an awesome and free opensource toolkit, which also allows AJAX pulling.